# Using Aggregate and Max functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, aggregate-functions

I'm having problems with the below query, working in SQL Server.

```
SELECT  
        emp_id= CASE employee_id
        WHEN ''
            THEN RTRIM(last_name) + '_' + RTRIM(first_name)
            + '_' + RTRIM(gender) + '_'
            + RTRIM(race_ethnicity_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(high_degree_code) + '_' + RTRIM(position_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(assignment_code)
            ELSE employee_id
            END , 
        last_name, first_name, 
        assign_perc, 
            assignment_num,
        CAST((total_salary)AS NUMERIC (18,2))* CAST((assign_perc) AS NUMERIC (18,2)) AS salary,
        total_salary
FROM employee 
ORDER BY last_name, first_name, district_name
```

My script is a simple extraction of columns, creating a unique key through case statement for emp_id when its null. The problem im having is when multiplying the assign_perc with the total_Salary when that person has multiple assignments and taking the max salary when that sales person is only listed once.  For example - my expected results:

[image]

John Smith is only a part time worker having one assignment being listed only one time, so his assign_perc will be less than 1 but I still need the max salary rather than the aggregate total (assign_perc*total_salary).  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your results are not consistent with the SQL.  For John Smith, the salary and total_salary have the same value, yet the salary should by 0.75 * total_salary according to your query.

Comment: The results I provided are what I need.  My query is currently producing (.75*10400) = 7800 - salary for John Smith.

Comment: The solution is going to be really messy since you don't have a simple way of identifying the number of entries for a specific employee without a concrete employee_id.

Comment: Understood... Ive tried multiple subqueries, joining on the same table after the concatenation of the emp_id but I'm getting duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, this is excessively messy since you'll need to use the CASE statement to determine the virtual `employee_id`.  It would be *much* simpler if you can either refactor this CASE statement into a udf, or store the result in the table for goodness sake!

To clarify what this is going to do - you want to join the `employee` table on a table containing counts for each employee.  The count table would look like this:

```
SELECT employee_id, COUNT(*) AS employee_count
FROM employee
GROUP BY employee_id
```

Joining them together would look like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM employee
JOIN (SELECT employee_id, COUNT(*) AS employee_count
      FROM employee
      GROUP BY employee_id) ec
ON employee.employee_id = ec.employee_id
```

Your calculated salary would now become:

```
        CASE 
            WHEN ec.employee_count > 1 
                THEN CAST((total_salary)AS NUMERIC (18,2))* CAST((assign_perc) AS NUMERIC (18,2)) 
            ELSE total_salary 
        END AS salary,
```

And here is the complete query substituting the monstrous CASE statement in place of 'employee_id':

```
SELECT  
        CASE employee.employee_id
        WHEN ''
            THEN RTRIM(last_name) + '_' + RTRIM(first_name)
            + '_' + RTRIM(gender) + '_'
            + RTRIM(race_ethnicity_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(high_degree_code) + '_' + RTRIM(position_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(assignment_code)
            ELSE employee.employee_id
            END AS emp_id, 
        last_name, first_name, 
        assign_perc, 
        assignment_num,
        CASE 
            WHEN ec.employee_count > 1 
                THEN CAST((total_salary)AS NUMERIC (18,2))* CAST((assign_perc) AS NUMERIC (18,2)) 
            ELSE total_salary 
        END AS salary,
        total_salary
FROM employee
JOIN (SELECT CASE employee.employee_id
        WHEN ''
            THEN RTRIM(last_name) + '_' + RTRIM(first_name)
            + '_' + RTRIM(gender) + '_'
            + RTRIM(race_ethnicity_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(high_degree_code) + '_' + RTRIM(position_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(assignment_code)
            ELSE employee.employee_id
            END AS employee_id, COUNT(*) employee_count 
      FROM employee
      GROUP BY CASE employee.employee_id
        WHEN ''
            THEN RTRIM(last_name) + '_' + RTRIM(first_name)
            + '_' + RTRIM(gender) + '_'
            + RTRIM(race_ethnicity_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(high_degree_code) + '_' + RTRIM(position_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(assignment_code)
            ELSE employee.employee_id
            END) ec 
  ON CASE employee.employee_id
        WHEN ''
            THEN RTRIM(last_name) + '_' + RTRIM(first_name)
            + '_' + RTRIM(gender) + '_'
            + RTRIM(race_ethnicity_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(high_degree_code) + '_' + RTRIM(position_code) + '_'
            + RTRIM(assignment_code)
            ELSE employee.employee_id
            END = ec.employee_id
ORDER BY last_name, first_name, district_name
```